# How to make a slider with divs and variable width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a slider with divs:

```
<div class="slider">
    <div class="panel"></div>
    <div class="panel"></div>
    <div class="panel"></div>
    ... A lot more panels hidden by css ...
</div>
```

The project required them to be spaced equally and fluid. Jquery is being used. I achieved this by:

```
.slider {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: justify;
    height: fixed-height-here;
    overflow: hidden
}

.panel {
    display: inline-block
}
```

I am uncertain how to make them slide. There is a variable amount of elements, and the slider is variable width. I had the following idea:
    
    
        
        
        
        ... A lot more panels hidden by css ...

onclick:

```
$(".inner").css("width", page * 100); //expand the width
$(".inner").animate({"margin-left", -(page - 1) * $(".inner").innerWidth());
```

This works "ok" (but not quite idea) when it slides from page 1 to page 2, but it does not work sliding from page 2 to page 1.

How can I achieve the effect I am wanting?

Comment: Are each of them the same width? It sounds like you're trying to build a carousel, in which case I'd recommend checking out jCarousel or Flexslider, or searching for other carousels. http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/examples/ http://flexslider.woothemes.com/  The responsive jcarousel might be a good place to start: http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/examples/responsive/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a real simple "slider" with some "animation" you can play with [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/g9u74/3/).

JS

```
var i = 1;
$( ".sliderholder img:nth-child(" + i + ")" ).show(1000);

$('#forward').on('click', function(){
  $( ".sliderholder img:nth-child(" + i + ")" ).hide( "slide",
                                                     {direction: 'right'},
                                                     1000);
  i = i+1;
  if( i > $('.sliderholder img').length )
    { i = 1; }
    $( ".sliderholder img:nth-child(" + i + ")" ).show(1000);

});//end on click

$('#back').on('click', function(){
  $( ".sliderholder img:nth-child(" + i + ")" ).hide( "slide",
                                                     {direction: 'right'},
                                                     1000);
  i = i-1;
  if( i < 1 ) 
  { i = $('.sliderholder img').length; }
  $( ".sliderholder img:nth-child(" + i + ")" ).show( 1000);

});//end on click
```